# Check if an array contains a value in logstash

Tags: logstash

Let's say I have created a field like this:

```
"market": [
            {
              "name":  ["name1","name2","name3","name4","name5" ]
            },
              {"place":["P1","P2","P3"]}
          ]
```

Now, I want to check if the field "name" contains the value "name3" or "name4".

I've tried this filter.

```
filter {
elasticsearch {
                hosts => "localhost:9200"
                index=>"admin"
                query => 'market.name:(name3 OR name4)'
                sort => "_id:asc"                       
                fields => {host_machine =>  'host_machine' }
            }
}
```

But it doesn't do anything (no crash, no error message, just doesn't do anything).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine..just market field should not be with nested type..in that case (if it is nested) we use query_template option like this:

```
"query": {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "market",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "filter" : 
                   {"query_string" : {
                       "query" : "market.name:(name3 OR name4)"

                }
           }               
         }
    }
}
}
```